# Writing a jQuery ajax call into JavaScript's XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call like this :

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe"} $.ajax({ dataType : "jsonp", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data : JSON.stringify(data), success : function(result) { alert(result.success); // result is an object which is created from the returned JSON }, });
```

Now I need to convert it into JavaScript's XmlHttpRequest.
I know the basic syntax but I want to know how to convert this particular jQuery ajax into XmlHttpRequest.

Particularly how to mention dataType in XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Ajax request uses XHR request as core function to make the call. You can say it is wrapper with added checking and functionality to provide cross-browser compatibility and error correcting and checking mechanism

Comment: @Midhun1993 Yes, but my question is that how can I manually write each component of an ajax call especially dataType in XmlHttpRequest

Comment: check whether you can get some idea from here ... https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "request/url";
var data = {"name":"John Doe"};

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        successCallback(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));

function successCallback(arr) {

}
```

FYI : not tested code